# How can I use Firebase on my server side code without the Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, dart

I am writing a server-side application with dart. I intend to use firebase in it, but the current admin SDK only supports Java, Nidejs, Go, Python and C#. Is there an alternative way I can implement Firestore calls in dart.

Comment: Hi. Please read https://medium.com/icnh/writing-cloud-functions-in-dart-b7e62192b3bc this article

Comment: I don't think this is being maintained anymore. Will need to fix the main library and a lot of dependencies to make it work.